# string aggregate group and count on a value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have table like this.

```
 | table                        |
 | class_id| name    | gender   |
 +---------+---------+----------+ 
 |       1 | Jane    |     F    |
 |       1 | John    |     M    |
 |       1 | Tom     |     M    |
 |       1 | Bob     |     M    |
 |       2 | Jack    |     M    |
 |       2 | Kate    |     F    |
```

I have a query like this.

```
select id, array_to_string(array_agg(name), ' - '::text) as name_list from table
group by class_id
```

My result is

```
 | 1 | Jane-John-Tom-Bob |
```

But i'd like to count my gender count also i mean in the first group (cass 1) i need a column like 1 F + 3 M

My request is something like this and i'd like to use it in 1 group by.

```
 | 1 | Jane-John-Tom-Bob |1F + 3M
```

Comment: `array_to_string(array_agg(name), ' - '::text)` can be simplified to `string_agg(name, ' - ')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a filtered aggregate:

```
select id, 
       string_agg(name, ' - ') as name_list, 
       concat( 
            count(*) filter (where gender = 'F'), 
            'F + ', 
            count(*) filter (where gender = 'M'), 
            'M') as gender_count
from table
group by class_id;
```

If you are on an older Postgres version, you need to replace

```
count(*) filter (where gender = 'F')
```

with

```
count(case when gender = 'F' then 1 end)
```

(and the same for 'M')

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's great. For further use, if i don't know the values but i know a column that i can use for group by how can i use it in the filter? Maybe i can use more than 10 filter value.

Comment: @lokmancetin: sorry I don't understand you. The column you group by has nothing to do with the column you apply the filtered aggregate on

Comment: In your answer, the filter values are common like F and M. Simple. But what if the filter values is more than 50 i.e and this 50 values is also in the column in this current table. I can get his values by group by and i'd like to use these group byed values in the filter aggregate.

Comment: You can use any valid SQL expression in the `where` part of the filter

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution without using Filter aggregate

```
select tt.class_id, string_agg ( t,  ','::text) as gender, string_agg(distinct y,','::text) as name

from 

(

select class_id, count(gender)::text|| string_agg( distinct  gender, ','   ) as  t
       from string_test
group by class_id , gender

) tt , 

(
select class_id, string_agg( distinct name::text, ','::text ) as y
    from string_test
group by class_id
) yy
where tt.class_id=yy.class_id

group by tt.class_id
```

Result;

```
+==========+========+===================+
| class_id | gender | name              |
+==========+========+===================+
| 1        | 1F,3M  | Bob,Jane,John,Tom |
+----------+--------+-------------------+
| 2        | 1F,1M  | Jack,Kate         |
+==========+========+===================+
```